# Error while loading tidyquant in RStudio-1.1.463

Tags: r, rstudio

When trying to load the tidyquant package in RStudio-1.1.463, I get the following error message:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyquant’:
 .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'tidyquant', details:
  call: if (theme$dark) {
  error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I do not use the latest version because it is not compatible with my 32-bit machine. I did not have that issue while I was using the latest RStudio version so I suppose that causes the issue. Any workaround for this version?

Comment: Bump! I'm having the same problem. library(tidyquant, verbose = T)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyquant’:
 .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'tidyquant', details:
  call: if (theme$dark) {
  error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘tidyquant’ was built under R version 3.6.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. You cannot use a "Rstudio theme" that has "NA" in the dark variable. Long story short go to

Rstudio -> Tools -> Global Options -> Appearance

Change your theme to something that has a TRUE or FALSE in the Dark variable, how do you know? Change it then type this:

```
rstudioapi::getThemeInfo()
```

All I had to do was click the drop-down that said "Modern" and change it to "Sky" and it worked. Subsequently, tidyquant now loads correctly.